# Air Tickets Information

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="info">
<head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var info = angular.module("info",[]);
    info.controller("AirFlight", function ($scope) {
        $scope.Allinfo = [
        {Airline: "Air India", Stops: "1", Refundable: "Yes", Price: "2000"},
        {Airline: "Etihad", Stops: "0", Refundable: "No", Price: "4000"},
        {Airline: "Cathay Pacific", Stops: "0", Refundable: "No", Price: "3000"},
        {Airline: "Qantas", Stops: "0", Refundable: "No", Price: "6000"},
        {Airline: "Emirates", Stops: "1", Refundable: "Yes", Price: "3200"},
        {Airline: "Singapore", Stops: "0", Refundable: "No", Price: "7000"},
        {Airline: "Eva Air", Stops: "0", Refundable: "No", Price: "5000"},
        {Airline: "Lufthansa", Stops: "1", Refundable: "Yes", Price: "5100"},
        {Airline: "Nippon", Stops: "0", Refundable: "No", Price: "5800"},
        {Airline: "British Airways", Stops: "1", Refundable: "Yes", Price: "2500"}];

    }); 
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="bookPanel" class="panel" ng-controller="AirFlight">
        <h2 align="center"><strong><u>Welcome To International Flights Information</u></strong></h2>
        <h3 align="center">
        Search:<input type="text" id="search" ng-model="entry" placeholder="Search"/><br/>

        Stops:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type1" ng-true-value="No" ng-false-value="" />0.Non-Stop
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type2" ng-true-value="Yes" ng-false-value=""/>1.Stop<br/>

        Refundable:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type3" ng-true-value="Yes" ng-false-value="" /><br/>
        Price:<br/>
        2000<input type="range" id="slide" min="2000" max="7000" step="100" ng-model="Allinfo.Price" />7000 <br>
        <span>{{Allinfo.Price}}</span>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h4>Airline</h4></th>
                    <th><h4>Stops</h4></th>
                    <th><h4>Refundable</h4></th>
                    <th><h4>Price</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="List in Allinfo | filter: search.type1 | filter: search.type2 | filter: search.type3 | filter: entry | filter: Allinfo.Price | filter: Stops | orderBy:'Airline'" ng-class="$odd ? 'odd' : 'even'" />

                    <td>{{List.Airline}}</td>
                    <td>{{List.Stops}}</td>
                    <td>{{List.Refundable}}</td>
                    <td>{{List.Price | currency}}</td>                  
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi all i have been working on airplane tickets information using json format i wanna use range slider with it and json data should be shown according to price.Beside of this i am struggling with checkbox selection and multi-selection checkbox. I hault up here and struggling alot please help me in this..

Comment: You're supposed to ask a question. Not dump vague requirements and a wall of code, and hope that we guess what the problem is and fix it for you.

Comment: Welcome on SO. You should improve your question to get more attention. Keep in mind that the point of SO is to build a knowledge database out of real problems. This means you should turn your post so that the answers are not only useful for you but for others that may stumble upon the same issue. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

First you must include your range-slider in head section

```
<script src="your-slider.js"></script>
```

after add it as module dependency

```
var info = angular.module("info",['yourSlider']);
```

then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanx Hareesh but it's not reflecting the json data